# How to combine columns based on column name in R?

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926160/r-combine-columns-based-on-names), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158050/r-pivot-longer-combining-columns-based-on-the-end-of-column-names), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715670/combining-columns-based-on-partial-column-name). However, I cant get those solutions to work for my problem.

I'm trying to combine columns based on their names and then create a matrix/dataframe of every pair of variables. Hopefully my example will explain more clearly.

For example, imagine we have a data frame like the one below:

```
# create some data
set.seed(100)
dfOG <- data.frame(
  day = sample(c('1', '2'), 3, replace = T),
  rain = sample(c('yes', 'no'), 3, replace = T),
  val1 = runif(3)
)
```

I am applying a process (that is outside of my control) that splits the categorical variables into dummy variables (with a dummy for each level). In the end, I get a matrix where the columns are every pairwise variable. The output looks something like this:

```
# create matrix of all pairs
name2 <- c('day.1', 'day.2',
           'rain.yes', 'rain.no', 'val1')

nam2 <- expand.grid(name2, name2)
newName2 <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(nam2$Var1)){
  newName2[i] <- paste0(nam2$Var2[i], ":", nam2$Var1[i])
}
set.seed(100)
newMat2 <- matrix(rexp(75, rate=.1), nrow = 3, ncol = length(newName2))
colnames(newMat2) <- newName2
> newMat2
     day.1:day.1 day.1:day.2 day.1:rain.yes day.1:rain.no day.1:val1 day.2:day.1
[1,]    9.242116   30.973623      0.9311719      1.943265   20.23192   3.8058106
[2,]    7.238372    6.248052     17.4839077      5.251022   11.23247   0.7162231
[3,]    1.046449   11.744293      2.4999295      3.380434   11.31048   4.2160769
     day.2:day.2 day.2:rain.yes day.2:rain.no day.2:val1 rain.yes:day.1
[1,]    0.766974      17.576561      9.348420  0.9030936       2.066487
[2,]    4.979445       5.406032      3.905483  5.5516888       8.371235
[3,]   13.735530       1.925034      1.250488  6.5460690       9.214908
     rain.yes:day.2 rain.yes:rain.yes rain.yes:rain.no rain.yes:val1
[1,]       10.15267          7.067098         3.527963     13.420953
[2,]       19.75727         22.259788         9.411371     10.040507
[3,]       15.76831         11.416835         8.630324      1.451295
     rain.no:day.1 rain.no:day.2 rain.no:rain.yes rain.no:rain.no rain.no:val1
[1,]      4.330075    25.4360600        15.317283        0.349195     12.51062
[2,]      5.495578    11.0861832        11.256991       13.882071     30.86277
[3,]      6.680542     0.2620275         9.630859       36.926827     11.38734
     val1:day.1 val1:day.2 val1:rain.yes val1:rain.no val1:val1
[1,] 1.41956168   6.731429     14.124068    12.797966 41.294648
[2,] 3.69760484   6.137335      1.391675    12.639562  1.033024
[3,] 0.08002734  23.743638      6.804015     9.374034 27.107049
```

We can see above, that `newMat2` contains every pair of variables, after the categorical variables have been split into dummies.

What I'm trying to do is recombine those dummy variables back into a single variable by summing the appropriate column's rows. My final output would be a matrix/dataframe of every pair of recombined variables.

For example, if we just look at the variable `day`. This variable has been split into `day.1` and `day.2`. If I recombined this variable for every pair we would have a column for `day.day`, `day.rain`, and `day.val1`. Doing this manually could look like this:

```
day.day  = apply(newMat2[,c(1,2,6,7)], 1, sum)
day.rain = apply(newMat2[,c(3,4,8,9)], 1, sum)
day.val1 = apply(newMat2[,c(5,10)], 1, sum)
```

In the above code, I'm summing (row-wise), the columns that should be combined.

**Desired output:**

More explicitly, If I were to recombine the entire of `newMat2` manually, it would look like this:

```
dfNew <- data.frame(
            day.day  = apply(newMat2[,c(1,2,6,7)], 1, sum),
            day.rain = apply(newMat2[,c(3,4,8,9)], 1, sum),
            day.val1 = apply(newMat2[,c(5,10)], 1, sum),
            rain.day = apply(newMat2[,c(11,12,16,17)], 1, sum),
            rain.rain = apply(newMat2[,c(13,14,18,19)], 1, sum),
            rain.val1 = apply(newMat2[,c(15,20)], 1, sum),
            val1.day = apply(newMat2[,c(21,22)], 1, sum),
            val1.rain = apply(newMat2[,c(23,24)], 1, sum), 
            val1.val1 = newMat2[,c(25)] 
)
> dfNew  
   day.day  day.rain day.val1 rain.day rain.rain rain.val1  val1.day val1.rain
1 44.78852 29.799418 21.13501 41.98529  26.26154  25.93157  8.150991  26.92203
2 19.18209 32.046444 16.78415 44.71027  56.81022  40.90328  9.834940  14.03124
3 30.74235  9.055886 17.85655 31.92579  66.60485  12.83863 23.823666  16.17805
  val1.val1
1 41.294648
2  1.033024
3 27.107049
```

However, in my real data, I have over 1000 columns, some with many different factor levels and as a result, manually combining them would take a long time. Is there any way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse` functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

newMat2 %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "id") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  mutate(name = map_chr(str_extract_all(name, paste(c(colnames(dfOG), ":"), collapse = "|")),
                        paste0, collapse = "")) %>% 
  group_by(id, name) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

  id    `day:day` `day:rain` `day:val1` `rain:day` `rain:rain` `rain:val1` `val1:day` `val1:rain` `val1:val1`
1 1          44.8      29.8        21.1       42.0        26.3        25.9       8.15        26.9       41.3 
2 2          19.2      32.0        16.8       44.7        56.8        40.9       9.83        14.0        1.03
3 3          30.7       9.06       17.9       31.9        66.6        12.8      23.8         16.2       27.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rlist)
df <- as.data.frame(newMat2)
L <- split.default(df, f = gsub("(^[a-z0-9]+).*:([a-z0-9]+).*$", "\\1.\\2", colnames(df)))
rlist::list.cbind(lapply(L, rowSums))

      day.day  day.rain day.val1 rain.day rain.rain rain.val1  val1.day val1.rain val1.val1
[1,] 44.78852 29.799418 21.13501 41.98529  26.26154  25.93157  8.150991  26.92203 41.294648
[2,] 19.18209 32.046444 16.78415 44.71027  56.81022  40.90328  9.834940  14.03124  1.033024
[3,] 30.74235  9.055886 17.85655 31.92579  66.60485  12.83863 23.823666  16.17805 27.107049
```